# Can you make the html textbox only accept a certain format?

Tags: html, textbox, format

I have a Html textbox on my page, now I want it so you can only edit the values that are set on it.

Example:

Set value: 0:00 - 0:00
User can change it to: 8:30 - 9:30 or 11:30 - 12:35

I want to do it the correct way that the user can only insert this, not that I have to do a php check if he did edit the format.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _I have a Html textbox on my page_, you mean `<input type="text">`?

Comment: @matewka Yes, sorry if I didnt make that clear.

Comment: You'll have to do some Javascript client side validation. Is that your question?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a time picker. If so, there's no need to reinvent the wheel. [There are plenty of user-friendly time pickers available on the web.](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=jquery+time+picker) Choose one you like and use that

Comment: @thatidiotguy No I am looking for a textbox that only accepts a edit on those numbers.. I've saw it before a while back.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a plugin you're looking for:

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Where you can create masks to make a "custom" input format:

```
$("#startTime").mask("99:99 - 99:99",{placeholder:"0"});
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33Qtf/7/)**